# Fetchnig from an array which store multiple arrays in Codeinghter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array, suppose given below,

```
$store_array[] = $details_order;
$store_array[] store all arrays ($details_order) like given below
```

and now on view side in `MVC`, i want to fetch each value from each array. what i will do,

Comment: this is the very core basics of using an mvc, you should read the manual here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: actually i need foreach loop, i am confused how to implement foreach loop to fetch array in $store_array[],

Answer (score 0):

As you want for loop you may try like this this

```
foreach($array as $arr):
echo $arr['name'];
endforeach;
```